# Is rocksdb WriteBatch thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, rocksdb, rocksdb-java

For example, one class has a private db, and a public method-`put` .
We got several threads to run the `put`, is this ok ? (ps: we don't consider the order of the k/v )

```
void put(List<byte[] keys, List<byte[]> values) {
      WriteOptions writeOpt = new WriteOptions();
      WriteBatch batch = new WriteBatch();
      for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); ++i) {
        batch.put(keys.get(i), values.get(i));
      }
      this.db.write(writeOpt, batch);
}
```

The [doc here](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/Basic-Operations) says that

```
However other objects (like Iterator and WriteBatch) may require external synchronization. 
If two threads share such an object, they must protect access to it using their own locking protocol.
```

But for the example above, the threads don't share the same `WriteBatch`, they own its own `WriteBatch`, and write to the db. So I wonder if this is ok?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I known, this is ok. 
RocksDB uses a `WriterThread` to handle the multithread write.
And all the writers will go into a `JoinBatchGroup`, if the writer of current thread gets the so called `group_leader`, it gonna write. The whole process has no competition.

I'm a freshman to this, and I don't be sure about the above statements. Can anyone fix me if I'm wrong ?